# How to use Tornado with a thread pool?

Tags: python, threadpool, tornado

I am coming from Java background and absolutely new at Python.

I need to write a simple web server to handle multiple concurrent requests. The request processing is mostly CPU bound and handling a single request may take 100 - 1000 ms. The server will run on a multicore machine.

I was advised to use `Tornado` with a thread pool. Do you have any example ?

Comment: have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/methane/2185380

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I probably need multiple _processes_ rather than threads as it's explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the processing of a single request is mostly CPU-bound, a thread pool won't help. Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) prevents more than one thread from running Python in any one Python process. Instead, start a Tornado process per core.

[Follow this example from the Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html):

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(0)  # Forks multiple sub-processes
IOLoop.current().start()
```